# Android Native: CMake linking error: undefined reference to GL functions - even though EGL & GLESv3 included and linked

Tags: android, c++, cmake, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am trying to update a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tsaarni/android-native-egl-example), which is a basic OpenGL rendered cube, to a current Android version and project structure. The CMake script seems to be missing something, which I can't figure out. Is it a simple issue of lines in the wrong order?

System: Arch Linux - Kernel 5.0.9, Android Studio 3.5 Canary 13, CMake 3.14.3, Ninja 1.9.0

I created a new Native project in Android Studio and filled in the configurations with the old data. You can see the progress [here](https://github.com/DevSnobo/android-native-egl-example/tree/upgrade/refactor_to_new_project_structure). I am stuck at trying to link the GL function libraries to the .cpp files, as the terminal output tells me there are undefined references to certain gl... functions.

Terminal output:

```
Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /usr/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a nativeegl}
  ninja: Entering directory `/home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a'
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/nativeegl.dir/renderer.cpp.o
  [2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnativeegl.so
  FAILED: /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnativeegl.so 
  : && /home/snobo/Android/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi28 --gcc-toolchain=/home/snobo/Android/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/snobo/Android/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++14 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnativeegl.so -o /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnativeegl.so CMakeFiles/nativeegl.dir/jniapi.cpp.o CMakeFiles/nativeegl.dir/renderer.cpp.o  /home/snobo/Android/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/28/liblog.so -landroid -lGLESv3 -lEGL -latomic -lm && :
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:230: error: undefined reference to 'glShadeModel'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:236: error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:237: error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:238: error: undefined reference to 'glFrustumf'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:262: error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:263: error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:264: error: undefined reference to 'glTranslatef'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:265: error: undefined reference to 'glRotatef'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:266: error: undefined reference to 'glRotatef'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:268: error: undefined reference to 'glEnableClientState'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:269: error: undefined reference to 'glEnableClientState'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:272: error: undefined reference to 'glVertexPointer'
  /home/snobo/projects/AndroidNativeExample/app/src/main/jni/renderer.cpp:273: error: undefined reference to 'glColorPointer'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Here is one of the methods that includes the errors from above:

```cpp
void Renderer::drawFrame()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -3.0f);
    glRotatef(_angle, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(_angle*0.25f, 1, 0, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FIXED, 0, vertices);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FIXED, 0, colors);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);

    _angle += 1.2f;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(AndroidNativeExample C CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(
        nativeegl
        SHARED
        jniapi.cpp renderer.cpp)

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib
        log)
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(nativeegl Threads::Threads)

add_library(app-glue
        STATIC
        ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)

target_link_libraries(nativeegl ${app-glue})
target_link_libraries(nativeegl ${log-lib})
target_link_libraries(nativeegl android)
target_link_libraries(nativeegl GLESv3)
target_link_libraries(nativeegl EGL)
```

To my knowledge (which indeed is quite limited) this should link all necessary libraries and not result in an error. But somehow a few function references are undefined.

Please let me know if you have any ideas, I will try each and give feedback.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this problem? I have the same problem and I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing functions `glShadeModel` etc are OpenGL functions and are not available in OpenGL ES.

As your project managed to compile (and failed when linking) you must be including OpenGL headers from another source instead of the OpenGL ES header from the Android NDK.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was confused since Ctrl+B (Go to declaration) brought up the GLES/gl.h file, but that declaration is inside a 
`#ifndef GL_VERSION_ES_CM_1_0
#endif '
block.

And thanks to that hint I just realized that these are fixed functions. I will need to rewrite that code to modern OpenGL.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Richard Critten Can you please share what this another source is? I'm facing this problem right now and have no idea what to do, I scratched the entire web and found nothing helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DanielRotnemer by _"..another source.."_ I mean that OpenGL headers must also be installed and CMake is finding these by mistake rather than the OpenGL ES headers. Or some 3rd party library you are using has been built against OpenGL rather then OpenGL ES.

Comment: @Richard Critten Thanks for your response, I know I need to use a functions loader to load the addresses of GL functions. But i have no  idea how to do that. I added glew to my project, and I can't figure out how to initialize it

Comment: _"...I need to use a functions loader ..."_ not on Android just linking with the library provided with the NDK is enough.